# How I do permanently authorize an app on my mac?

Tags: applications, security

I use Clean My Mac to periodically clean out old log files and caches. Right before the clean, it asks me permission and I have to enter my password to authenticate. Is there any way I can authorize the app once and skip this step every time?

Comment: Related question and answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119771

Comment: Worth mentioning that caches do not need cleaning, unless there is a problem. Emptying caches regularly will reduce system performance.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's asking for authentication not because the app needs it but because it's altering system files and OS X will always need authentication for this.

Comment: This. Eactly how `sudo` behaves.

Comment: Actually, would also be interesting to see if it follows `sudo` timeout rules (by default, if you use `sudo` on the CLI, the OS won't request the password again for another 10 minutes or so). So, start CleanMyMac, run it, and enter the password. Close it, and see if it requires the password again - if it doesn't it's using `sudo` timeouts. If so, you could extend the timeout to infinite (i.e. never require it again) - but this is not recommended ever. See how to change the timeouts here: http://osxdaily.com/2016/05/05/change-sudo-password-timeout/

Comment: Er, this question is 7 years old. No idea why it's on the front page!

Comment: @Fiddle It’s on the front page because there’s a new answer. There’s no problem with responding to something from a long time ago, that’s encouraged on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on how the application requests authorization.

## Authorization Services

If the application is well designed, the request will be through [Authorization Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/authorization_services) provided by macOS. In this case, you need to determine which [authorisation right or rights](https://dssw.co.uk/reference/authorization-rights/) are being requested by the application.

A well designed Mac application will define their own unique rights. A reasonably well designed application will use an existing right defined by Apple.

Once you know the rights involved, you can modify the security policy database to lessen or even remove the authorisation restrictions. The database is modified with the [`security`](https://dssw.co.uk/reference/security.html) command line tool included with macOS; see the `authorizationdb` flag for making changes to the authorisation policy database.

All this is *not recommended* because you are actively reducing the security of your computer.

As an aside, Authorization Services are not available to applications sold in the Mac App Store or sandboxed applications.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is a way to completely authorise the “Clean My Mac” application. The reason why it asks you to confirm your password is that you are authorising the app and to make sure it doesn’t starts by itself. Trust me, even I feel frustrated because of this, but in a whole, asking of permission is a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't start by itself"?

Answer (score -2):

you can find the binary in the application folder, according to view package content, and to run the binary in sudo mode