# Allow a single app temporary administrator privileges

Tags: applications, macos, administrator

I have a standard user who runs a piece of software that allows them to repair storage devices (flash disk/SD cards/on board storage for specific cameras/etc) which needs administrator privileges to run properly in OSX 10.11

Is there a way to permanently grant admin accesses to a single app so it can run properly without needing an admin password every time?

Will add more details about the software, but still waiting a reply from user.

Comment: Try this method: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119771/how-can-i-give-an-app-permanent-permission-so-it-doesnt-ask-for-my-password-eve

Comment: Sorry to drift off-topic, but I'd love to know what software that is - sounds like it could be very useful.

Comment: Found out the app is called 'Card Rescue' version for Mac and Windows: [link](https://www.cardrecovery.com)